# Sending data to store with action, and making axios post request on same button click. Axios posts before the store data comes

Tags: reactjs, redux

Container: Login
Child components: => ContentBox => Form

This is Login Container:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { userCredentials: state.userLogin };
};

const Login = ( props ) => {

    const postLogin = ( e ) => {
        axios( {
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login-user",
            data: {
                email: props.userCredentials.email,
                password: props.userCredentials.password
            }
        } ).then( ( response ) => console.log( response ) ).catch( ( e ) => console.log( e ) );
    };


    return (
        <div id={"login"}>
            <ContentBox submitLogin={postLogin}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect( mapStateToProps )( Login );
```

And the Form Child Component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { stateInput: state.loginInput };
};

const Form = ( props ) => {
    const [ input, setInput ] = useState( { email: "", password: "" } );

    const handleEmail = ( event ) => {
        setInput( { ...input, email: event.target.value } );
    };

    const handlePassword = event => {
        setInput( { ...input, password: event.target.value } );
    };

    const submitDispatch = () => {
        store.dispatch( {
            type: "LOGIN_INPUT",
            payload: { email: input.email, password: input.password }
        } );
    };

    const submitForm = ( props ) => {
        props.submitLogin();
    };

    return (
        <div className={"form"} id={"loginForm"}>
            <button onClick={() => store.dispatch( {
                type: "LOGIN_INPUT",
                payload: { email: input.email, password: input.password }
            } )}>DISPATCH
            </button>
            <form method={"POST"}>
                <input value={input.email} onChange={handleEmail} name={"email"} type="text"
                       placeholder={props.placeholder[0]}/>
                <input value={input.password} onChange={handlePassword} name={"password"} type="text"
                       placeholder={props.placeholder[1]}/>

                <button className={"submit-button"} onClick={( e ) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    submitDispatch();
                    submitForm( props );

                }}>LOGIN
                </button>

            </form>

        </div>
    );
};


export default connect( mapStateToProps )( Form );
```

And then the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    userLogin: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    }
};

function rootReducer( state = initialState, action ) {
    if ( action.type === LOGIN_INPUT ) {
        return {
            ...state,
            userLogin: {
                email: action.payload.email,
                password: action.payload.password
            }
        };
    }
    return state;
}

export default rootReducer;
```

Now the issue:

In the Form Component, I have a button that triggers an action with redux, which sends what the user typed in the input fields (Email and password), this works correctly with the store, and I do receive it in the Login container in the form of props.userCredentials.

However: In the same button, I also want to trigger the axios call to post to my node backend, to find a user. But when I do, the axios call always receives the initial state of "" in email and password, but when I log the props.userCredentials in the Form container, I do receive the new state from redux.

I tried setting a setTimeout in the Form container and log the redux store, however then every other log I receive "", and the other log I receive the actual correct state.

How to best achieve this set up, with the button (on the form), to have both the axios call and the send to redux store?

The reason I have it like this is because I want the containers to make the axios calls, and the containers to not contain any JSX (easier to read), so I had to pass the axios call function down as props to the children.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is add the axios call to redux and dispatch it there.

Example:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
   return dispatch => {
       return axios( () => {
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login-user",
            data: {
                email: props.userCredentials.email,
                password: props.userCredentials.password
            }
        }).then(res => { 
            dispatch( {
                type: "LOGIN_INPUT",
                payload: { email, password }
            }) 
        })
   }
}
```

You can use this function with { login } in your login container.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, however now i Keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitLogin' of undefined" after I submit

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you click the button the callback from container is called, and at that time your store has the previous state, if you want to just send the same data you can pass as a parameter to your submitLogin callback as

```
const submitForm = () => {
    props.submitLogin({ email: input.email, password: input.password });
};
```

and in your container you can get this as

```
const postLogin = ( data ) => {
    axios( {
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login-user",
        data: {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
        }
    } ).then( ( response ) => console.log( response ) ).catch( (e) => console.log( e ) );
};
```

Hope it helps